# Hibernate : Jointable to join a particular child table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, join

I have two set of inheritance tables : 
1. TableA (inherited by TableA1 and TableA2),
2. TableB (inherited by TableB1 and TableB2)

DiscriminatorColumn for TableA is 'type' and DiscriminatorValues are 'A1' and 'A2' for TableA1 and TableA2 respectively.
Similarly, DiscriminatorColumn for TableB is 'type' and DiscriminatorValues are 'B1' and 'B2' for TableB1 and TableB2 respectively.
I have a join table TableA_B for joining TableA & TableB. I know that the join table TableA_B can link TableA1 to TableB1 only and TableA2 to TableB2 only and this happens according to the 'type' column. ie, A1 always links to type B1 and A2 always links to type B2.

Now, my problem is, when I am doing a query from TableA1, the @JoinTable generates the sql which joins TableA1, TableA, TableB, TableB1 and TableB2. Here, querying from TableB2 is unwanted. Is there any way to restrict this? As I mentioned, the only discriminating factor is the 'type' column.

TableA Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public class TableA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String type;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(
        name="TableA_B",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="A_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="B_id")}
        )
    private Set<DataMaster> inputData = new HashSet<DataMaster>(0);


//getters & setters ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA1")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="AId")
@DiscriminatorValue("A1")
public class TableA1 extends TableA{

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long AId;
    private String value1;
//getters & setters ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA2")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="AId")
@DiscriminatorValue("A2")
public class TableA2 extends TableA{

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long AId;
    private String value2;
//getters & setters ...
}
```

TableB is as follows :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public class TableB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
//getters & setters ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB1")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="BId")
@DiscriminatorValue("B1")
public class TableB1 extends TableB{
    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long dataId;
    private String value1;
//getters & setters ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB2")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="BId")
@DiscriminatorValue("B2")
public class TableB2 extends TableB{
    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long dataId;
    private String value2;
//getters & setters ...
}
```

DAO :

```
public TableA1 find(Long id) {
      Session session = DBSessionManager.getFactory().openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      TableA1 tableA1 = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         tableA1 = (TableA1)session.get(TableA1.class, id);
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }     
      return tableA1;
}
```

I tried using FilterJoinTable as :

```
@FilterJoinTable(name="dataTypeFilter", condition=":dataType = type")
```

and in the DAO,

```
session.enableFilter("dataTypeFilter").setParameter("dataType", "B1");
```

but, this also didnt give the expected result.

This is how I added filter :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
@FilterDef(name="dataTypeFilter", parameters = {
        @ParamDef(name = "dataType", type = "string")
        })
public class TableA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String type;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(
        name="TableA_B",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="A_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="B_id")}
        )
    @FilterJoinTable(name="dataTypeFilter", condition=":dataType = type")
    private Set<DataMaster> inputData = new HashSet<DataMaster>(0);


//getters & setters ...
}
```

DAO :

```
public TableA1 find(Long id) {
          Session session = DBSessionManager.getFactory().openSession();
          Transaction tx = null;
          TableA1 tableA1 = null;
          try{
             tx = session.beginTransaction();
         session.enableFilter("dataTypeFilter").setParameter("dataType", "B1");
             tableA1 = (TableA1)session.get(TableA1.class, id);
             tx.commit();
          }catch (HibernateException e) {
             if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
          }finally {
             session.close(); 
          }     
          return tableA1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code with the `@FilterDef` and `@FilterJoinTable` shown - it's hard to know exactly what's going on without seeing the `@FilterDef`

Comment: I have updated the question with the filter code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, you should have a ManyToMany association between TableA1 and TableB1 and another ManyToMany association between TableA2 and TableB2. But you mapped these two associations as a single association between TableA and TableB. You should map these two associations as what they really are:

```
private class TableA1 extends TableA {
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<TableB1> tablesB1s;
}

private class TableA2 extends TableA {
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<TableB2> tablesB2s;
}
```

I wouldn't use the same join table to map two different associations. I'm not even sure it's possible.